# CORS workaround in Angular.js $HTTP POST?

Tags: angularjs, cors, http-post

Is there a workaround to sending POST request cross-domain via Angular, besides using a proxy? Below request is refused, ie: OPTIONS , net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED    It's just form data I want to submit to friend's local server for school project.

```
$scope.postJSON = function(){
        var objJson = angular.toJson($scope.event);
        console.log(angular.toJson($scope.event));
        delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://friendslocalserver.com',
            data: objJson
        }).success(function() {
            console.log("POST Json object worked!");
        }).error(function(){
            console.log("POST Json object failed!");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure AngularJS for CORS. Your friend's server needs to support CORS requests and probably whitelist your domain. This depends heavily on the HTTP server used.